# Removing dynamically created child nodes from a form with js / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, paypal

The below post was hugely helpful for what I'm trying to do:
[Builing a cart with multiple items and the PayPal button in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981243/multiple-items-with-paypal-button-and-php)

This part works beautifully:

```
    var inp1 = document.createElement("input");
    inp1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    inp1.setAttribute("id", "item_number_" + current_item);
    inp1.setAttribute("name", "item_number_" + current_item);
    inp1.setAttribute("value", current_item);

    document.getElementById("paypal-form").appendChild(inp1);
```

but I'm getting a bit stuck on how to remove an item when needed... I am looking for something like:

```
    document.getElementById('payPalForm').removeChild(inp1);
```

But obviously I need a way to specify/track those dynamically created id's... or is there an easier way I'm missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use the parentNode property to retrieve the parent element of an element, and use the removeChild method of the parent:

```
inp1.parentNode.removeChild (inp1);
```

Reference:
[parentNode property](http://help.dottoro.com/ljjcoorg.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where this code belongs, but it would be helpful to encapsulate this within a class.

```
function NewClass() {
    var formPP = document.getElementById('payPalForm');
    var lInputs = [];
    this.addItem = function(val) {
        var inp1 = document.createElement("input");
        inp1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        inp1.setAttribute("id", "item_number_" + val);
        inp1.setAttribute("name", "item_number_" + val);
        inp1.setAttribute("value", val);
        formPP.appendChild(inp1);
        lInputs.push(inp1);
    }
    this.removeItem = function(val) {
        var e = formPP.firstChild;
        while( e ) {
            var eNext = e.nextSibling;
            if( e.value == val )
                formPP.removeChild(e);
            e = eNext;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to tailor this to meet your needs, but hopefully this gives you a start.