# Add paypal buy now button dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple items with PayPal button and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981243/multiple-items-with-paypal-button-and-php)

I want to add paypal Pay now (or Buy now button) dynamically, I have a fixed price lets say 20$ okay just for example, I want Pay now button to be added next to each item that I upload, how to do so?

I'm currently trying to do it, but maybe I'm going the wrong way so i want to hear what you have to say:) I really need to know how, paypal documentations are so confusing

if i can do it in more than 1 way, then give me the simplest way :D

thank you in advance :D

**EDIT**

I want to dynamically add this code next to each item uploaded to my site,

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="585258558585z">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="The Tittle  xyz</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0"
```

the thing is with paypal pay now (buy now button) you have to assign an item name, I want to update the item name each time a new item is uploaded and i want to put a pay now button next to it

**EDIT**

@afuzzyllama

in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348761/automatically-create-buy-now-button-paypal) he created a buy now button like this

```
<?php
echo '<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Teddy Bear">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!">
</form>';
```

it's a button like mine but with 1 difference, that's why I came to here to ask the question lol, you see that code is very basic, you have to assign an item which is teddy bear.

I don't want to assign an item, I want that every time I upload an item, it gets assigned automatically

lets say i uploaded a watch then a paypal pay now button should be placed dynamically next to my watch, then I uploaded a picture of a tv another paypal button should be placed next to the picture - but i have a fixed price to all of the items on my site lets say 20$, I guess i have to connect to mysql, pull the items you see

Comment: there are [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348761/automatically-create-buy-now-button-paypal) to your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981243/multiple-items-with-paypal-button-and-php) already!

Comment: @afuzzyllama Thank you a lot, i don't know why i haven't seen these questions!

Comment: @afuzzyllama sir I just checked the links you gave me, this http://bit.ly/qTIvYo is a basic button and this http://bit.ly/pEjNLv is a shopping card

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348761/automatically-create-buy-now-button-paypal) states `The following page lists the minimum-required information for a Buy Now button.` Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: @afuzzyllama please read my edit :D

Comment: @Robert Harvey THANK YOU AND THANKS TO EVERY1 WHO VOTED TO CLOSE THIS QUESTION....NOW I CAN NO LONGER OFFER A BOUNTY AND WILL NEVER HAVE A GOOD ANSWER

Comment: THERE ARE 1 MILLION RESULT OF A SHOPPING CART ON GOOGLE, AND 1 TRILLION SOFTWARE LIKE ZEN-CARTE...WHY WOULD I COME TO STACKOVERFLOW IF I WANT A SHOPPING CART?!!!!!!